# C - Recursive function smaller prime numbers

Tags: c, recursion

i got this exercise where it wants me to create a function to check if a number is "Prime", and than create another function to print how many smaller prime numbers are there from the one i checked. The thing is i need to create a recursive function to check the number of smaller prime numbers using the first function(the one that checks if a number is prime or not). This is what i got so far, and i'm stuck here. The recursive function is confusing for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a;
   scanf("%d", &a);
   checkPrime(a);
   smallerPrime(a);
}

int checkPrime (int number) {
    if(number % 2 == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
int smallerPrime (int number) {
        if(checkPrime(number) % 2 != 0){
            return ;
        } else {
            return ;
        }
}
```

Comment: Go read on what a Prime is. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: you can use the `checkPrime` function to do both but basically you just need to recursively call check prime with the arg passed `-1` but the important bit is the base case that checks if the arg `==2` where 2 is the smallest prime

Comment: @mad.meesh I know i can do both with checkPrime but in the exercise it says that i must do it with another recursive function.

Comment: and like the guy with the funny name above me says you’re not actually checking for prime here you’re just checking for parity basically

Comment: ok well with your second function do what i said and that is calling the function recursively with `arg-1`

Comment: @mad.meesh Parity is what i wanted to ask but English isn't my main language so i confused the terms...

Comment: oh then if it’s parity then just keep calling the function with `arg-2` that is if `arg` is even to begin with otherwise you will need a special case that calls it with `-1`

Comment: @Leaf then if it's not primes you are looking for, then please correct your questions. Otherwise it's confusing and people in the feature that happen to find your question will be confused as well.

Comment: "Parity" - you keep using that word, I do not think it means what you think it means :-) I would suggest "evenness" as an alternative, if you need a property, otherwise just use a phrase like "check if a number is even".

Comment: Your smaller prime function isn't returning anything.  Your check prime function isn't doing a good job; it gives the wrong answer for 9 and 15, for example.  There are lots of questions about primes on SO; please go and look at them for ideas.  Once you've got your basic prime checker working sensibly, you can move on to the recursive "how many smaller primes" function.  Having said that, you could code it more efficiently if your prime checker kept a track of how many prime factors it had tried.  Sieve of Eratosthenes is a good search term.  You don't needs Atkins

Comment: I should also mention that using recursion to find all even numbers below a given number is a spectacularly *bone-headed* idea (you may want to use more tact than I, if you communicate that to your educator). The best use cases for recursion are where the "solution search space" is reduced a *lot* in each recursion level (like halved in a binary search). Recursively finding all even numbers less than `100,000,000` is not going to do your stack any favours :-)

Comment: To check _parity_ recursively `int checkParity (unsigned number) { return number ? checkParity(number / 2) ^ (number % 2) : 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw from the comments,that you actually want to check if a number is even,and if so,you want to know how many smaller even numbers there are using recursion,not prime numbers as mentioned in the title,so my answer will refer that.

You could use something like this:

```
int smallerPrime (int number) {
    static int count = -1; // so that the number itself will not be counted
if(number <1)   //excluding 0 or negative numbers
        return 0;
    if(number !=2) {//we know the number has to be even so no check is needed
            ++count;
       smallerPrime(number - 2);
        return count+1; // the +1 is in order to count 2 as well
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
```

So for example:
Input 10 would give output 4 (8,6,4,2)

As mentioned by paxdiablo,using recursion here is not the best idea.

In case of very big numbers,your program will probably crash.

Furthermore,note that this code works for positive numbers only,as i am not sure if you want to count anything but them(Negative numbers (like -2,-4 and so on) and 0 are also considered even).
I excluded them here.

In main,you need to put the return value of `checkPrime` in some variable,and use it to determine if you need to use `smallerPrime` function.
So you should correct that in your code.

Of course,you can do it all in one function with some small changes.